# Cloud9 Dashboard not loading (will not load)

Tags: dashboard, cloud9-ide

I've just signed up on Cloud9.  My Dashboard is Not Loading (I'm hung on the Loading your Dashboard page.  Opened a new tab and got "workspace is not attahed message".  Any ideas?

Comment: Please describe in detail what you have tried so far.

Comment: You're most likely using IE. Support for IE has long been on our wishlist and we're almost there: our IDE already works most of the time with IE (just try going to a workspace URL directly with https://ide.c9.io/username/workspace and it should work reasonably well), but the biggest obstacle is the dashboard right now. Since IE is less than 2% of our website userbase, we decided to launch with support for Chrome, Firefox, and Safari first, and implement IE support when we launch our new dashboard within a few months. So please keep an eye on our blog/Twitter/Facebook for updates on this soon!